# SQL Server Nested Select

Tags: sql-server, database, join, nested

I am just learning to use SQL Server to query a database (and eventually to create my own). I am basically trying to replicate a lot of work that I have already done with Excel, but that's beside the point.

**EDIT**: this may be a clearer query -

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(mi,-10,GetDate())
SET @EndDate = GetDate()
SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT StartDateTime, TagName, Value
FROM History
WHERE TagName IN ('Master', 'Running')
  AND DateTime >= @StartDate
  AND DateTime <= @EndDate
```

This returns something like this:

```
Row     StartDateTime             TagName     Value
-----------------------------------------------------
1       2016 07 27 15.01.39       Master       154
2       2016 07 27 15.01.39       Running        0
3       2016 07 27 15.01.40       Master       154
4       2016 07 27 15.01.40       Running        0
5       2016 07 27 15.01.41       Master       154
6       2016 07 27 15.01.41       Running        1
7       2016 07 27 15.01.42       Master        65
8       2016 07 27 15.01.42       Running        0
```

You can see that the `StartDateTime` is repeated over two rows. Is it possible to get the values for one `StartDateTime` in the same row?

Comment: So you want to select records where the TagName is 'MasterFaults' OR the TagName is 'Running' AND value is 1?

Comment: "Basically I need to only select the rows for 'MasterFaults' TagName where the Value for 'Running' = 1." there's exactly 0 results that have tag name of both 'Running' and 'MasterFaults'. Something is wrong with your logic.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT StartDateTime
    , TagName
    , Value
FROM History
WHERE DateTime >= @StartDate
    AND DateTime <= @EndDate
    AND
    (
        TagName = 'MasterFaults'
        OR
        (
            TagName = 'Running'
            AND 
            Value = 1
        )
    )
```

--EDIT--

You have significantly changed the question. Sadly it still is not very clear what you want. Maybe this will push you in the right direction.

```
SELECT m.StartDateTime
    , m.TagName as MasterTagName
    , m.Value as MasterValue
    , r.TagName as RunningTagName
    , r.Value as RunningValue
FROM History m
left join History r on r.StartDateTime = m.StartDateTime and r.TagName = 'Running' and r.Value = 1
WHERE m.TagName = 'Master'
    AND m.DateTime >= DateAdd(minute, -10, GetDate())
    AND m.DateTime <= GETDATE()
```

If this still is not what you are looking for you should read this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Also, you really should avoid using reserved words for column names. It makes writing queries a lot more painful. (DateTime, Value etc...)

Comment: Not exactly.  I'm only interested in returning the values for the Masterfaults tag.  But the Value for 'Running' at the coresponding StartDateTime must be 1.  I think I may have a simpler and clearer query now, will just edit my question

Comment: @jamsandwich when you say 'corresponding' how do the records correspond?  do they have matching StartTimeDate?  That might be ok as long as events are guaranteed to have different time and dates

Comment: Precisely @AndrewDeighton I've changed my original question now.  Maybe I should have kept the previous question there but I thought this might have a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT H1.StartDateTime, H1.TagName, H1.Value, H2.TagName TagNameR, H2.Value ValueR
            FROM History H1 
                Join 
                History H2 
                    ON 
                        H1.DateTime = H2.DateTime 
                        AND
                        H1.TagName = 'Master'
                        AND
                        H2.TagName = 'Running'
            WHERE 
                 DateTime >= @StartDate
                 AND 
                 DateTime <= @EndDate;
```

H1 and H2 are aliases for the tables with the same name